# Inconsistent Behavior: Printing C++ Struct Properties in Python using ctypes gives unexpected results

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I'm writing a c++ library that I'm importing in python with `ctypes`. The library implements a function `Wtf returnwtf()` that returns an object of type `Wtf` and I want to print the objects properties in Python. The code however behaves strangely.

Here is a minimum non-working example:

```cpp
// wtf.cpp
#include <cstdint>

extern "C" {
struct Wtf {
    uint32_t z = 513;

    Wtf(Wtf const &state);
    Wtf(){
        z = 514;
    }
};

Wtf returnwtf(){
    Wtf w = Wtf();
    return w;
}

Wtf::Wtf(Wtf const &state) = default;
}
```

```py
# testwtf.py
import ctypes

class Wtf(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("z", ctypes.c_uint32),
    ]

my_lib = ctypes.CDLL("./libwtf.so")

returnwtf = my_lib.returnwtf
returnwtf.restype = Wtf

print(returnwtf().z)
```

```bash
g++ -c -Ofast -fPIC -o wtf/wtf.o wtf/wtf.
g++ -Ofast -shared -o wtf/libwtf.so wtf/wtf.o
python3.10 testwtf.py
```

I would expect it to print `514` but instead it prints random numbers like `143882176` or `1011496896`.

Now when I move the implementation of the copy constructor inside the struct like so

```cpp
struct Wtf {
    uint32_t z = 513;

    Wtf(Wtf const &state) = default;

    Wtf(){
        z = 514;
    }
};
```

or remove the copy constructor completely it works fine and prints `514` as expected.
It also changes it's behavior when the struct consists of multiple members. If for example the class consists of 5 uint32_t like so:

```
struct Wtf {
    uint32_t z = 513;
    uint32_t a = 513;
    uint32_t b = 513;
    uint32_t c = 513;
    uint32_t d = 513;

    Wtf(Wtf const &state); // implementation outside of struct like in the first example

    Wtf(){
        z = 514;
        a = 1;
        b = 1;
        c = 1;
        d = 1;
    }
};
```

it works perfectly fine where it wouldn't with only one member. But when I substitute `uint32_t` with `uint16_t` (and c_uint32 with c_uint16 in Python) I get a `SIGSEGV`

I'm out of ideas what I am doing wrong because I'm not able to narrow down the problem. I think it has something to do with the way the compiler structures the return data but I can't get a hold of the issue.

How can I get a consistent result?

```
gcc version 11.4.0
Ubuntu 22.04
```

Comment: @wuefelfreak C APIs typically return structures via output pointer parameters, e.g. [GetWindowRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect)

Comment: It may be C++ return-by-value doesn't conform to the `ctypes` "C" expectation.  I don't have access to a compiler at the moment to experiment.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Is there a way that I can ensure that the return-value conformes with the expectations? I tried manipulating the packing attribute but it didn't work.

Comment: The "c" in `ctypes` stands for *the C programming language*. Not for *any programming language derived from C* or *any language which happens to have the letter C in the name*. It won't necessarily work with C++ types that are not also C types. `extern "C"` won't help here.

Comment: I guess that the System V ABI is used by Ubuntu, so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57932525/returning-a-struct-in-systemv-abi may be interesting.